# Order post by meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-key

I have a custom post type called: `business`, each post has a metabox with meta key `country`.

I want to order posts by meta value and only display 3 posts for each meta value:

New york:

- post title has meta value new york
- another post title has meta value new york
- another post title has meta value new york

France

- post title has meta value France
- another post title has meta value France
- another post title has meta value France

PS : Each meta value are generated from another post type `places`

My code :

```
$n = 0;
$args = array(
 'post_type'=>'business'
);
$query_biz = get_posts($args);
foreach ($query_biz as $biz) {

    $theme_meta  = get_post_meta($biz->ID,'country',true);

    if($theme_meta == 'France'){

        if($n < 3):
            echo $biz->post_title.'<br/>';
        endif;

    } ...

$n++;

}
```

Globally I want to separate posts by meta value as this :

New york: <=== meta value
|-post title has meta value new york
|-another post title has meta value new york
|-another post title has meta value new york

France <=== meta value
|-post title has meta value France
|-another post title has meta value France
|-another post title has meta value France

And only limit post result at 3 for each meta value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
if($n == 0)
  echo $biz->post_title.'<br/>';
else
  echo '<p>' . $biz->post_title . '</p>;
```

Comment: Thank you but its not match what i want to achieve, i just want to separate post of post type by meta value

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
<?php
// New Vars
$posts = array();
$post_limit = 3;

$args = array(
 'post_type'=>'business'
);
$query_biz = get_posts($args);
foreach ($query_biz as $biz) {

    // Get post country
    $theme_meta  = get_post_meta($biz->ID,'country',true);

    // Check if county key exits in array
    if (!array_key_exists($theme_meta, $posts)) $posts[$theme_meta] = array();

    // If more than post_limit don't add
    if ($post_limit <= count($posts[$theme_meta])) continue;
    // Else add post to array
    else array_push($posts[$theme_meta], $biz);

}

// Print Titles
foreach ($posts as $country => $_posts) {
    echo '<h2>Country: ' . $country . '</h2>';

    foreach ($_posts as $post) {
        echo '<p>' . $post->post_title . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @user44321 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the green check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.